# Hadoop job fails, Resource Manager doesnt recognize AttemptID

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

Im trying to aggregate some data in an Oozie workflow. However the aggregation step fails.

I found two points of interests in the logs: The first is an error(?) that seems to occur repeatedly:

After a container finishes, it gets killed but exits with non-zero Exit code 143.

It finishes:

```
2015-05-04 15:35:12,013 INFO [IPC Server handler 7 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000048_0 is : 0.7231312
2015-05-04 15:35:12,015 INFO [IPC Server handler 19 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000048_0 is : 1.0
```

And then then when it gets killed by Application Master:

```
2015-05-04 15:35:13,831 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000048_0: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

The second point of interest is the actual error that crashes the job completely, this happens in the reduce-phase, not sure if these two are related though:

```
2015-05-04 15:35:28,767 INFO [IPC Server handler 20 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000051_0 is : 0.31450257
2015-05-04 15:35:29,930 INFO [IPC Server handler 10 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000052_0 is : 0.19511986
2015-05-04 15:35:31,549 INFO [IPC Server handler 1 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000050_0 is : 0.5324404
2015-05-04 15:35:31,771 INFO [IPC Server handler 28 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000051_0 is : 0.31450257
2015-05-04 15:35:31,890 ERROR [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Error communicating with RM: Resource Manager doesn't recognize AttemptId: application_1430730089455_0009
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Resource Manager doesn't recognize AttemptId: application_1430730089455_0009
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator.getResources(RMContainerAllocator.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator.heartbeat(RMContainerAllocator.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMCommunicator$1.run(RMCommunicator.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException: Application attempt appattempt_1430730089455_0009_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor.makeRemoteRequest(RMContainerRequestor.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator.getResources(RMContainerAllocator.java:667)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException): Application attempt appattempt_1430730089455_0009_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:77)
    ... 11 more
```

After that the oozie:launcher job and the job that got the error just sit there indefinitely with STATE:accepted, FINALSTATUS:undefined and TRACKING UI:unassigned.

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how I can fix it?
The same workflow worked before, and I couldnt say that I changed anything inbetween...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just in case somebody else stubles upon this error: It seemed like this was caused due to hadoop running out of disc space... Pretty cryptic error for something as simple as that. I thought ~90GB would be enough to work on my 30GB Dataset, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the similar issue, In my case task got completed successfully. But it took very much time to finish and there were very large logs on jobtracker, most of the log entries were from the progress report such as the following ones :

```
2015-05-04 15:35:12,013 INFO [IPC Server handler 7 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000048_0 is : 0.7231312
2015-05-04 15:35:12,015 INFO [IPC Server handler 19 on 49697] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1430730089455_0009_m_000048_0 is : 1.0
```

On debugging my code I found that distributed cache was getting read through the map function of Mapper class, **After moving the logic of reading dist-cache data from map function to configure method of Mapper class**, my issue got resolved.

We should have to use configure method for such kind of operations which are mainly related with configurations or the code blocks which we need to process only once before calling map function.