# Application attempt appattempt_*** doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache

Tags: apache-spark

I have written a Spark streaming application which loads from checkpoint data. I executed my application a number of times and then kill my application using yarn kill command..I sometime get the following exception in my application when reloading:

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException: Application attempt appattempt_1474609292954_0147_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2032)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2030)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.allocate(AMRMClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.allocateResources(YarnAllocator.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$1.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:368)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException): Application attempt appattempt_1474609292954_0147_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2032)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2030)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:77)
    ... 10 more
```

I am deploying my application on yarn (cluster mode) using Spark 1.6 and Mapr 5.2 version.

Comment: I got the same error along with RM doesn't recognize attemptid Till now only reason i found is low disk space , see the below post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033043/hadoop-job-fails-resource-manager-doesnt-recognize-attemptid

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer was already found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30391973/983722).
The answer is fortunately very straightforward:

> It seemed like this was caused due to hadoop running out of disc space.

Obvious resolutions being an increase in diskspace or reduction in disk space usage.